# Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner

Tags: dns, smtp, spf

I am using the MDaemon Email Server. When I test my domain (mail.mydomain.com.sg) with MX Lookup, it shows the following error:

SMTP Banner Check   Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner

How do I fix this error?

I already checked ptr:my Email Server IP Address and mx:my Email Server IP Address, it shows properly. I also added a SPF/TXT record in my domain.

please advice me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PTR record should be the host name, not the IP address.  The PTR record is the reverse lookup.

Also, do you have the A record that points your HOST name to your IP address?  You need that as well.

Comment: "You can think of the PTR record as an opposite of the A record. While the A record points a domain name to an IP address, the PTR record resolves the IP address to a domain/hostname. PTR records are used for the reverse DNS (Domain Name System) lookup."

Comment: I already added the A record that points my Host Name (mail.mydomain.com.sg) to my IP Address (Public IP Address).

Comment: And did you fix the PTR record?

Comment: PTR record will need Hostname (in your case mail.mydomain.com.sg). To fix MX loookup error, determine from which IP address your emails are being sent. You can simply test it by sending an email to your self and check what IP listed as the sender.

Now, set this IP address's PTR record to mail server's hostname (mail.mydomain.com.sg). Most probably, you will have to ask your ISP/web hosting provider to set the PTR record.

Answer (score 1):

Check your hostname of the server and fix it. example

mail hostname - mail.xxx.in and external dns pointer to server is mail.xxx.com will create the problem and you will get this error.In this case please change server hostname to mail.xxx.com. restart the network of the server or restart the server.

Please make sure your isp added ptr record correctly.

Good Luck.